# Use both empty and string filters in dplyr's filter

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I'm updating an old script using the deprecated `dplyr::filter_()` to use `dplyr::filter()`. But I can't get it to work for empty filter strings anymore:

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
my_df <- tibble::tibble(x = sample(c(0:9), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

deprecated `filter_()` works for both string and empty strings

```
fil1 <- "x == 5"
filter_(mydf, .dots = fil1) # works

fil2 <- NULL
filter_(mydf, .dots = fil2) # works, returns all values
```

NSE version works only with quoted filter values, but not with empty ones

```
fil1 = quo(x == 5)
filter(my_df, !!enquo(fil1)) # works

fil2 = NULL
filter(my_df, !!enquo(fil2)) 
Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector

fil2 = quo(NULL)
filter(my_df, !!enquo(fil2))
Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector
```

I see three possible approaches to this:

- quote `NULL` differently
- use another expression instead of `NULL`
- use another argument inside `filter()`

Comment: You say it's in a script any reason you can't wrap it in a condition and test for "nullness"?

Comment: @Chuck P - sure I could, but that seems like an ugly workaround, I would have to do it in several places, and worst of all, doesn't still my curiosity as to how I can feed NULL into filter().

Comment: No comment on what would be ugly not having seen your whole script.  I have a workaround for you with your second bullet though.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify your filters as lists of expressions (or NULL), you can use the unquote-splice operator to effectively "paste" them as arguments to filter. Use `parse_exprs()` to convert strings to expressions:

```
fil1 <- rlang::exprs(x == 5)          # Note the s on exprs
filter(my_df, !!!fil1)                # Works

fil2 <- NULL                          # NULL
filter(my_df, !!!fil2)                # Also works

fil3 <- rlang::parse_exprs("x==5")    # Again, note the plural s
filter(my_df, !!!fil3)                # Also works
```

The first and the third calls are effectively `filter(my_df, x==5)`, while the second call is effectively `filter(my_df,)`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly @timm-s the second bullet option means I can offer this solution.

```r
set.seed(2020)
library(dplyr)

my_df <- tibble::tibble(x = sample(c(0:9), 100, replace = TRUE))

fil1 <- quo(x == 5)
filter(my_df, !!enquo(fil1)) # works
#> # A tibble: 11 x 1
#>        x
#>    <int>
#>  1     5
#>  2     5
#>  3     5
#>  4     5
#>  5     5
#>  6     5
#>  7     5
#>  8     5
#>  9     5
#> 10     5
#> 11     5

fil2 <- TRUE
filter(my_df, !!enquo(fil2)) 
#> # A tibble: 100 x 1
#>        x
#>    <int>
#>  1     6
#>  2     5
#>  3     7
#>  4     0
#>  5     0
#>  6     3
#>  7     9
#>  8     5
#>  9     0
#> 10     7
#> # … with 90 more rows
```

It simply relies on the fact that `filter` relies on true/false so instead of telling it nothing tell it true.  For me the real question was why `filter_` thought NULL was true LOL.

A little more playing revealed it's possible to simplify more for the empty case

```r
fil3 <- TRUE
filter(my_df, fil3)
```

will also work but may not fit your circumstances.